# Laravel многие ко многим между pivot таблицами

Tags: laravel, eloquent

У меня есть 2 таблицы - birds (Какие-то данные о птице, например цена) и sellers(Какие-то бонусы для птицы, например птица стоит на 10% дешевле). И pivot таблица bird_seller.
У каждого продавца (seller) может продаваться несколько птиц. Я реализовал это через many to many связь.

Так же есть таблица users. И я хочу ,чтобы у каждый пользователь мог иметь птицу, которую продает продавец, то есть мне нужно сделать связь многие ко многие между таблицей users и таблице bird_seller. Чтобы пользователю можно было получить птицу, например, стоимостью 100 и скидкой 10% (Данные из таблицы birds и sellers)

Как реализовать такую связь? Какую таблицу нужно создать, какую модель сделать для bird_seller таблицы? Как работает many to many я понимаю, но как сделать именно в моем случае?..

Comment: Если вопрос в том, как связать разные сущности через несколько pivot таблиц, то Лара это не умеет, но умеет [этот пакет](https://packagist.org/packages/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep)

Comment: Возможно это то, что мне и нужно! Я пропробую

Comment: Там есть примеры как это работает. Я связывал 3-4 таблички и сломал голову, пока подобрал правильный порядок полей.

Comment: Чтобы установить этот пакет ,как я понял, мне нужен ларавель 8, а у меня 7, но если обновиться до 8, то там тоже вылазят конфликты, например с laravel/ui

Comment: Problem 1
    - staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep[v1.13, ..., v1.13.1] require illuminate/database ^8.0 -> found illuminate/database[v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - Root composer.json requires staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep ^1.13 -> satisfiable by staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep[v1.13, v1.13.1].

Comment: @Total Pusher Хм, по документации там User → many to many → Role → many to many → Permission. Но мне нужно что-то типа такого - `Users -> many to many -> (Birds -> many to many -> PIVOT -> Sellers )` ТО есть `Users -> many to many -> PIVOT`

Comment: Не до конца понимаю что вам нужно. Если в итоге хотите получать pivot таблицу, то сделайте для нее также модельку через `extends Pivot`. Вот в мане написано что я имею в виду: [Defining Custom Intermediate Table Models](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models). PS. Если хотите ставить пакет под старую версию Лары, то нужно ставить более старую версию пакета. Выберите то, что нужно на packagist, там справа все версии, если прощелкать, показывает зависимости. Может v1.12 поставится

Comment: Вот, скорее всего это мне и нужно. Но там написано "Если вам нужно мягко удалить сводные записи, подумайте о преобразовании вашей сводной модели в реальную модель Eloquent." Думаю так будет правильнее сделать. Но не совсем понимаю как ее преобразовать в реальную модель. (Soft delete возможно пригодится в будущем). И ещё как правильно назвать pivot таблицу для user и bird_seller? Bird_seller_user?

Comment: Достаточно `class BirdSellerUser extends Pivot {}`. Название модели должно быть такое, чтобы Лара могла угадать название таблицы. Либо, прописать `protected $table = "bird_seller_user";`, тогда будет использовано оно. И это название использовать в `hasManyDeep`. Вот пример из реального проекта `class GroupsRoles extends Pivot { protected $table = "groups_roles"; }` `public function userRoles(): HasManyDeep { return $this->hasManyDeep('App\Role', ['App\GroupsUsers', 'App\GroupsRoles'], ["user", "group", "uuid"], ["uuid", "group", "role"] ); }`

Comment: @Total Pusher Да, у меня уже получилось это сделать) И я заметил, что можно наследоваться не только от класса `Pivot`, но и от `Model`. И еще один мини вопросик. В классе `User` я определяю отношение `many-to-many` c таблицей `bird_sellers`. Как сразу получать записи по id из `bird_sellers`? Например, в `bird_sellers` поле `bird_id`. И нужно получить вместе с юзером Bird по id. Спасибо)

Comment: Я добавил такой код в свой User.php `public function my_birds() {'user_id', 'bird_seller_id')

        return $this->belongsToMany(
            'App\models\Sold_bird',
            'bird_seller_user',
            'user_id',
            'bird_seller_id');
    }` А в AuthController.php что-то вроде этого `auth()->user()->load('my_birds')->my_birds()`. И мне возвращается pivot table с полями bird_id и seller_id. Как от сюда получить Bird и Seller? Сто вариантов с with, withPivot перепробовал - не получается(

Comment: Так) У меня получилось. Я добавил belongsToMany в bird_seller, чтобы можно было получить доступ к Bird. Завтра ответ напишу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я сделал модель Sold_bird (Хотя правильнее назвать ее Bird_seller)
И унаследовал ее от Model, хотя от Pivot работает точно так же.

```js
class Sold_bird extends Model {
  protected $table = 'bird_seller'; // sold_bird is alias

  // return bird
  public
  function bird() {
    return $this - > belongsTo(
      'App\models\Bird',
      'bird_id',
      'id'
    );
  }

  // return seller and certificate
  public
  function seller() {
    return $this - > belongsTo(
      'App\models\Seller',
      'seller_id',
      'id'
    ) - > with('certificate');
  }
}
```

В User.php я добавил такое отношение (Из-за неправильного названия пришлось менять некоторые параметры)

```js
public
function my_birds() {
  // sold_bird is alias. Real table is bird_seller
  return $this - > belongsToMany(
      'App\models\Sold_bird',
      'bird_seller_user',
      'user_id',
      'bird_seller_id') -
    > withPivot(['count', 'id']) -
    > with('bird') -
    > with(['seller' => function($query) {
      $query - > select('id', 'certificate_id'); // return only certificate that seller give
    }]);
}
```

А так же создал таблицу `bird_seller_user`

То есть нужно работать, как с простой моделью

Answer (score 0):

я вижу это так(и лара так умеет):

users -> users_birds_pivot <- birds -> birds_sellers_pivot -> sellers

тебе не нужно записывать всё в одну таблицу, можна записать что у юзера 1 есть птица 1, а уже у птицы 1 есть свойства 1, тоесть юзер не будет ничего знать про скидки и т.д, ей нада знать только  про птицу, которая у него есть, а уже потом отдельным запросом он узнает про скидки на эту птицу.

Если режет глаз, что запроса будет 2, можеш сделать 1, только с multijoin-ом, потом просто select(), и выбираеш что тебе нада с всех 5 таблиц. (оч удобная штука, ссылку оставлю: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#advanced-join-clauses), если сам не поймёш, напишу запрос, там не сложно.

P.S Если что не так понял - поправте

Comment: Нет, мне, наверное, такая структура не подойдет. Тк мне нужен отдельный список птиц ,и отдельный список продавцов, и отдельный список птиц пользователя. У каждого продавца может быть несколько птиц (many to many bird_seller. И там прописываются скидки и тд), И у пользователя может быть несколько птиц (Не просто птиц, а именно птиц, которые продают продавцы)